# dplyr compilation issue, Rcpp.h: no such file or directory

Tags: r, ubuntu, dplyr

Attempting to compile `dplyr` in Ubuntu (`r-base` and `r-base-dev` are up to date):

```
R -e 'install.packages("dplyr", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")'
```

Compilation gives this error:

> `RcppExports.cpp: ..fatal error: Rcpp.h: no such file or directory`

I tried uninstalling and re-installing Rcpp:

```
sudo apt-get remove r-cran-rcpp
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcpp
```

I tried to compile again but got same error.

Comment: Have you tried installing `Rcpp` from R with `install.packages('Rcpp')`? It's probably a matter of where it's installed; if you're installing with `apt-get`, make sure wherever it sticks it is in `.libPaths`.

Comment: @alistaire thank you for the response.  Earlier I tried unsuccessfully to install Rcpp and dplyr from R.  I did use apt-get for the successful Rcpp install, so I will check .libpaths.

Answer (score 1):

Rcpp related problem is common in fedora27.
Make sure R-Rcpp-devel and R-core-devel are installed.

```
dnf install R-core-devel
dnf install R-Rcpp-devel
```